# Excel on Mac automatically converts all numbers to thousands

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I'm on Excel 14 for Macintosh.

It automatically converts all numbers to be representative of thousands. I have searched throughout to change a preference or option and cannot find it.

#### Example

```
 1234 is  1.234
  568 is   .568
12678 is 12.678
```

This is on all existing and new worksheets.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Please describe exactly what is happening.  What are you typing and what are you seeing?  How are computed results affected?  Also, are you in the U.S.?  If not, how do you write numbers?  For example, how would you write the number that is 200×300?  How about 1/4 (as a decimal)?  (And does your computer know where you are?)

Comment: I have a feeling that [this is what you're looking for](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/72304). Don't forget to reboot after changing your regional settings

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed your default sheet take a look at this article while it is for Excel on windows it should be the same concept you will just need to remove the sheet from the XLSTART folder or get a blank sheet from another good computer and use that in the folder.

http://www.vitalyst.com/2011/03/productivity-101-setting-up-excel-default-formatting/

Here are the instructions incase the link ever goes bad:

1. Open Excel to a blank workbook.
2. Format the blank file with all options desired. For example, set margins, cell color formats, or set up a header or footer. Make sure to remove any values you entered in cells to test formatting unless you want them to appear in every blank workbook.
3. Once your changes are made, click on the File tab and choose Save As.
   From the “Files of type” drop-down list, select “Excel Template (*.xltx)” and change the file name to “Book.”
4. Set the “Save in” location to the XLSTART folder. This folder is typically located in a path similar to C:Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/XLSTART. (Check out TechRepublic’s tip for quickly finding the XLSTART folder.)
5. Click Save.
6. Quit and re-open Excel. The blank workbook should contain the formatting you previously set.